# Errors Type 'Interpolation' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationWithTheme<any>' of emotion and Twilio, dependencies clashing

Tags: reactjs, twilio, string-interpolation, emotion, peer-dependencies

I have been using "@emotion/styled": "11.10.5", and didn't have any problem, but since I started using the Twilio library "@twilio/flex-webchat-ui": "^2.9.1", now the terminal is full of errors like this ones: ([error logs picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TteKO.png))

> ```
> error TS2322: Type 'SerializedStyles' is not assignable to type
> '((string | number | boolean | ComponentSelector | Keyframes |
> SerializedStyles | ArrayInterpolation<undefined> |
> ObjectInterpolation<...> | ((theme: any) => Interpolation)) & (string
> | ... 7 more ... | FunctionInterpolation<...>) & (string | ... 5 more
> ... | ClassInterpolation)) | null | undefined'.   Type
> 'SerializedStyles' is not assignable to type '((theme: any) =>
> Interpolation) & FunctionInterpolation<Theme> & CSSObject'.
> Type 'SerializedStyles' is not assignable to type '(theme: any) => Interpolation'.
> Type 'SerializedStyles' provides no match for the signature '(theme: any): Interpolation'.
>
> <Span css={value}>{copy}</Span>
>
> node_modules/@emotion/core/types/index.d.ts:96:7
> css?: InterpolationWithTheme<any>
>
> The expected type comes from property 'css' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { css?: Interpolation<Theme>; } & { theme?: Theme | undefined; as?: ElementType<any> | undefined; } &
> ClassAttributes<...> & HTMLAttributes<...> & { ...; }'
> ```

As I noticed, **Twilio** is also using emotion but different packages and versions (deprecated ones):

> "create-emotion-styled": "^9.2.6",
>
> "emotion-theming": "9.2.6",
>
> "react-emotion": "9.2.6",
>
> "emotion": "9.2.6",

([twilio package.json picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HSGp.png))

I tried to solve this peer dependencies clash by adding in the "resolutions" section of my project's package.json the emotion versions, (and the React and React Dom versions as told here [How can I avoid a TypeScript error with FlexPlugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73161610/how-can-i-avoid-a-typescript-error-with-flexplugins)) but it didn't solve the problem: ([resolutions section of my package.json picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWvAd.png))

Comment: First of all, check whether updating the package `@emotion/styled` to latest (in package.json of Twilio package), resolves your main error?

Comment: how could I update twilio's packages? twilio is a third party library that uses an old version of emotion, which has different packages... twilio doesn't even use the package @emotion/styled (it uses the 4 packages I listed in the post)